# Hibernate ORM design strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I need to build a Vehicle domain object.  All Vehicle objects will have about 5 properties... no big deal.  I annotate the class with @Entity, slap in an id annotated with @Id.  My problem is, there are two other types of specialty vehicles I need to account for.  One needs to hold 2 additional string values, and the other needs to hold a list of strings.

I would like to be able to do a findAll() and get all of the vehicles, so I'm not really sold on creating completely separate domain objects for the other two types of vehicles and having completely separate tables for them.  I toyed around with an idea to create an "AdditionalProperties" abstract class, make it a member of Vehicle, then extend it for my two specialty vehicles, but I quickly got lost in the proper way to annotate it and map it to the database. But even then I'd be stuck with writing lots of monolithic if statements to check vechicle type and cast that class etc etc

My other thought was just to include the extra fields in the single Vehicle domain object I have now (even though they don't make any sense for all the other types of vehicles) and leave the values null except for when it is one of the specialty vehicles.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I should approach this with possibly some examples of how the classes should be annotated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you simply create two subclasses of Vehicle, and containing the additional properties? Hibernate supports inheritance just fine. You'll have three options to persist the entity inheritance tree:

- everything in a single table (often the fastest and simplest option)
- every entity in its own table
- common properties in a common table, and additional sub-entity properties in their own table.

Whatever solution you choose, selecting vehicles will select all the kinds of vehicles satisfying the criteria. Hibernate queries are polymorphic.

Read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e6906).

Comment: Do I have to annotate Vehicle as @MappedSuperclass?  Does that let me instantiate / persist a Vehicle class that isn't extended? Or are they both annotated as @Entity?  I think I'd like to go with the first option where they're all in the same table...

Comment: No. MappedSuperclass and Entity are exclusive. MappedSuperclass is used when you want to inherit common persistent fields into several, otherwise unrelated, entities (like using a BaseEntity class which has a `lastModified` field, for example). In your case, you have a functional inheritance, and Entity must be used. If the Vehicle class isn't asbtract, then yes, you can persist bare Vehice instances, in addition to sub-entity instances. All entities, including Vehicle, must have the Entity annotation.

Comment: Following the example in the documentation works perfectly.  I built a factory to return type Vehicle, but based on the type passed in, it creates the appropriate concrete class and returns it. I use Spring to return AJAX to the client and even though I have a collection of Vehicles, it automatically recognizes the concrete implementation class and returns the extra values for each one.  Thanks a lot!